# Cannot download from Azure not public blob storage with Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Getting **object has no attribute 'read'** when trying to download file from Azure not public blob storage with Azure Storage SDK for Python

```
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name = account_name, account_key = blob_key)
    blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name,remote_file_name,local_file_name)
```

I generated SAS token with expiration date but there is no information how to use it with  **BlockBlobService** ? It works fine for public files.

Answer (score 2):

you can actually use the following syntax:

```
bbs = BlockBlobService(account_name='<account_name>', sas_token='<sas_token>')
```

More information can be found in this [**repo**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/advanced/authentication.py)

When it comes to the 'read', please ensure that the SAS has all required access to read blob services as well(worth double checking):
[image]

Comment: I will look into repo ASAP. Regarding 'read' access I pick READ permission when creating SAS token, don't see the same options as you are showing above (3x'Allowed')

Comment: Ah I see it could be on the container level, this one is on a storage level sas